# Scheme's define in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, scheme, common-lisp, declarations, local-variable

In Common Lisp, we have to use the `let` form to declare a new lexically-scoped variable. This means that the code either looks like that written in C89 (all variables declared on top of scope), or acquires unreadably deep nesting. `let*` is somewhat useful, but is not always applicable.

Scheme 'solves' this problem by having a `define` form, that allows a lexical variable to be declared without creating a new nesting level.

So, the question is, is it possible to have Scheme-like variable declarations in Common Lisp, that do not increase the nesting level?

Comment: Of course, you could just write a macro that rewrites a list with let-like forms in them to the nested let-form.

Comment: @Cubic Right, but I wanted to make sure if there are some hidden gotchas with the obvious approach (considering I wasn't able to find any library that actually does that, despite people complaining about "Lots of Irritating Superfluous Parenthesis" since forever).

Comment: I posted you question literally at ChatGPT and got an interesting answer, refering to `destructuring-bind`. Unfortunately, I am not a Common Lisp expert and cannot evaluate the quality of that answer - but maybe you try this by yourself?

Comment: @DocBrown Well, I can rejoice that ChatGPT isn't going to take my job then, since `destructuring-bind` is used to declare a bunch of variables whose values are members of a list (kind of like pattern matching).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `LET` when using `DEFUN`: you can define local variables in the parameter list:

```
(defun foo (a)
  (let ((b (expt a 3)))
    (+ a b)))
```

is also

```
(defun foo (a &aux (b (expt a 3)))
  (+ a b))
```

That's not often seen in code, but it is a standard feature of Common Lisp.

Notice also that the syntax of `LET` and `DEFUN` is different in CL from what you are used to in Scheme: `CL:LET` allows declarations before the Lisp forms. `CL:DEFUN` allows documentation and declarations before the Lisp forms.

Note also that for example in *Scheme R7RS small* all internal `DEFINE` forms need to appear at the top of the enclosing form. Some Scheme implementations allow these forms to appear later in the body, but that is not in the *R7RS small standard*.

*Disclaimer: This answer was written only using natural intelligence.*

Comment: This is just like C89 however, where all variables have to be declared up front. Scheme's `define` provides for an alternative to both upfront declarations and deep nesting.